# If I bind a server socket to a device, will socket descriptors spawned from accept also be bound to the same device?

Tags: c, linux, sockets, network-programming

My question is whether the socket file descriptor returned from an accept() will inherit the bind device property of the server listener socket.

I am running on Ubuntu 12.04 using gcc 4.4.

Answer (score 2):

I believe the answer is technically no, but in practice you are likely to see little difference.

Binding your listen socket to a device will cause the socket to only listen to connections made to that that device. If you then `accept()` that socket, you will be returned an FD referencing a socket that was necessarily produced by referencing a connection made to that device. Whilst I believe that socket FD isn't technically speaking bound to that device, I don't think it would make a lot of difference if it was.

For instance, provided you did `bind()` on your listen socket, the server side IP address will (`bind()` or no `bind()` of the socket returned by `accept()`) be the guaranteed to be an IP address of the device you bound to. And `bind()` or no `bind()` of the socket returned by `accept()`, if your socket is an IP socket (TCP or UDP is irrelevant), the egress interface for packets is determined by the routing table, and not what interface the socket is bound to. For IP sockets, the `bind` device is really only relevant to listening. So the socket will *behave* like it is bound, but (AFAIK) is not technically bound itself.

Comment: Short follow up question. Could I get the desired affect by doing setsockopt bind device on the new fd following the accept? Then the any incoming sockets don't necessarily have to know the interface and then I can have my outgoing traffic go out through the desired interface. Would this work without a routing table modification?

Comment: Assuming this is an IP socket, egress traffic will *always* follow the IP rules AFAIK, and any `bind()`ing is irrelevant. If you have traffic destined to the correct IP address, then I believe what device you `bind()` the fd that `accept()` returns to is also irrelevant (i.e. if you are bound to device A and traffic ingresses through device B with a dest ip of device A, the connection will still work)

Answer (score 1):

If you create a socket via `socket(2)`, assign an address to it via `bind(2)`, optionally set options on it via `setsockopt(2)`, mark it as a passive socket by passing it to `listen(2)`, and then pass it to `accept(2)`, then on success `accept()` returns the file descriptor of a connected socket whose local endpoint is consistent with the characteristics of the socket passed to `accept()`.  In particular, whatever address and any device you assigned to the listening socket will be the address of the local end of the resulting connection.